# Prior art for WO2014035410A1 "Global feature library useable with continuous delivery"

Tags: prior-art-request, wo2014035410a1

I would like help finding prior art for [WO2014035410A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014035410A1).

This patent (filed Aug 30, 2012) describes using feature switches to toggle software features:

> The global feature library includes a feature switch for each of the plurality of features. ... The feature switch includes a feature value that turns a feature associated with the feature switch on and off based on a global value rule.

This seems like a standard industry practice well before the filing date, so I would like to document examples of prior art.

Comment: It may be helpful to include additional information for prior art request as detailed [here](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/a/146/9802)

Answer (score 2):

I've found several good examples already, simply from the Wikipedia entry for ["feature toggle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle):

There is a Flickr blog post from 2009: [Flipping Out](http://code.flickr.net/2009/12/02/flipping-out/)

Martin Fowler in 2010: [FeatureToggle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html)

And another from Disqus in 2010: [Partial Deployment with Feature Switches](http://blog.disqus.com/post/789540337/partial-deployment-with-feature-switches)

All these seem indicate that this was a wide-spread industry practice well before the 2012 filing date.

Answer (score 0):

Following arts are already known for this patent application:-

1. [WO1999060487](https://www.google.com/patents/WO1999060487A9?cl=zh) System and methods for object-oriented control of diverse electromechanical systems using a computer network
2. [US20120191760](http://www.google.co.in/patents/US20120191760) System and method for generating automatic user interface for arbitrarily complex or large databases
3. [US20080295045](http://www.google.co.in/patents/US20080295045) Method for Creating Hdl Description Files of Digital Systems, and Systems Obtained
4. [US20090319472](http://www.google.co.in/patents/US20090319472)  Event based organization and access of digital photos